# Selecting row value only if other rows are equal

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with an id column and a source column.
I want to return only the source values that all ids share.

E.g. in the table below id 1,2,3 all share 10 and 20, but id 3 is missing the source value 30, so 30 is not valid and I want to return 10 and 20.

I'm using MySQL and want to put this in a stored procedure.

How do I do this?

| id | source |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 3 | 20 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` function as the following:

```
SELECT source FROM
table_name
GROUP BY source
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM table_name)
```

To do this within a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getSourceWithAllIds() 
   BEGIN
   SELECT source FROM
   table_name
   GROUP BY source
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM table_name);
   END
```

The idea is to select the count of distinct id values for each source, which is done by `COUNT(DISTINCT id)... GROUP BY source`, then match this count with the distinct count of all id values existed in the table; `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM table_name)`.

If the two counts are equal, then the source have all the distinct ids existed in the table.

i.e. All distinct ids in the table are (1, 2, 3) count = 3, and distinct ids for a source =10 are (1, 2, 3) count=3. For source = 30, the distinct ids are (1, 2) count=2 so it will not be returned by the query (2<>3).

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SZivZIDC).

Comment: Really had a lot of trouble doing this. I in fact still do not fully understand your answer. But it works! Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I will add extra explanation to the answer.

Comment: The added explanation really helped me grasp this query! Thanks again!